# UWP - Page navigation within another Page ('iOS UIContainerView with UINavigationController embeded' equivalent?)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows, uwp-xaml

I'm porting an iOS app to a UWP project and there is something I'd love to do to save a bit of repetition but not sure how to do it.

On iOS I would embed a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIContainerView` and be able to push/pop only a section of the screen instead of pushing a full page on top of another.

Is there any way to do something similar on a UWP project? I effectively want to have a `Page` within a `Page`, and on the Inner page, be able to push a new page on top of that page.

Example: Have 3 navigation buttons along the top of the page. They are 'Tabs' which load 1 page per button into the area below it. It's a highly customised `TabBar`. The buttons would be nice to have in their own page with the content for each 3 pages in it's own page.

Currently I'm, doing this by either re-using the buttons along the top in multiple pages. Or I can swap out multiple `UserControl`s manually based on which button is pressed. One `UserControl` for each page.

Any help on the preferred method for this would be grand! 
Cheers,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do something similar on a UWP project? I effectively want to have a Page within a Page

If I didn't understand it wrong, you can use [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br242682(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame)%3bk(vs.xamleditor)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)&rd=true).

For Example: On MainPage.Xaml you can define one Frame with three `Button`s:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="btnPageOne" Content="Page One" Click="btnPageOne_Click"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnPageTwo" Content="Page Two" Click="btnPageTwo_Click"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnPageThree" Content="Page Three" Click="btnPageThree_Click"></Button>
        <Frame Name="MyFrame" Width="500" Height="600"></Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And on the click events of three buttons you can navigate the Frame to three pages:

```
private void btnPageOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageOne));
}

private void btnPageTwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageTwo));
}

private void btnPageThree_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageThree));
}
```

> and on the Inner page, be able to push a new page on top of that page.

You can define a button on PageOne inside a [StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.aspx) like below:

```
<Grid Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Name="myStackPanel">
        <Button  Name="myBtn" Click="myBtn_Click">Click Me to add Page</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in the `Click` event add new `Frames` to that StackPanel:

```
private void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Frame newFrame = new Frame{
             Width=100,
             Height=100
     };
     myStackPanel.Children.Add(newFrame);
     newFrame.Navigate(typeof(SubPageOne));
}
```

Here is the basic Demo that I made: [FrameNavigationSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/FramNavigationSample)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for, Cheers